# XSD validating value of child reference element

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I need to create an XSD that validates the value in a specific complex type from a different namespace with specific enumerations.

In this specific case the XML will look like this:

```
            <Format>
                <name>
                    <gco:CharacterString>IMG</gco:CharacterString>
                </name>
                <version>
                    <gco:CharacterString>Version 1.0</gco:CharacterString>
                </version>
            </Format>
```

It is a requiremement that all values validate as *gco:CharacterString* referenced from a seperate namespace (this is really a simple xs:string type in the other namespace, but I need to reference it).

I need *name* and *version* to validate for specific enumerations of values inside their *gco:CharacterString* child node.  In this case I want to validate that the following enumerations exist and are valid for *gco:Characterstring*:

name:
IMG
GEO
NIT

version:
version 1.0
version 2.0
version 3.0

Adding the enumerations to the referenced *gco:Characterstring* isn't an option, because I need these to be specific for both *version* and *name*.  Is this possible to set this up in the XSD?

Answer (score 1):

Not in XML Schema 1.0.

With XML Schema 1.1 - something like:

```
<assert test="(name/gco:CharacterString eq 'IMG)
              and (version/gco:CharacterString eq 'Version 1.0')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in XSD 1.0. There's a built-in assumption in XSD that the rules for validating elements in a namespace are context-free: that is, if one namespace imports another, the rules for elements in the second namespace won't depend on where the elements occur. I would suggest you're not using namespaces "properly".

Comment: The customer provided the XML specification and I can't change that.  I am looking for a way in XSD to still be able to validate the XML for valid entries.